# Convert sym links to junction

Tags: windows-10, symlink, junction

I have a folder with many many files, some are sym links. But these don't seem to work with a certain program. How can I either convert the symlinks to junctions or make a copy of the sym links (in situ) as junction links? Windows 10 / 64bit. Will need to work recursively of course.

Updated.

I have a folder with several thousand files.

That folder is organized with files and folders/sub folders etc.

For ease of organisation some files are sym links which point to a folder or file several folder-levels 'down'/lower

But a program I use doesn't read symlinks BUT can read junction links

How can I convert all the files that are symlinks to junction links so the program browser can navigate this folder properly?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be elaborative on the problem that you are facing.

Comment: Hello, thanks. 

OK I have a folder with several thousand files.

In that folder are organized files and folders. 

For ease some files are sym links which point to a folder or file several folder-levels 'down'/lower

A program I use now doesn't read symlinks BUT can read junction links


How can I convert all the files that are symlinks to junction links so the program browser can navigate this folder properly?